# Is there a pattern for implementing a static variable in Go?

Tags: go

I am having a brain freeze

I am trying to write a logging package to work with our enterprise logging system.

I want to create the logger and it associated data at the beginning and reuse it throughout the service lifetime.

something like this (pseudo code) at the entry point of the service

```
log := LogManager.CreateLogger("mylog", "DEBUG")
```

use the following code in the rest of the service and imported packages

```
log := LogManager.GetLogger()
```

log would be the same instance - the one instantiated at the beginning.

Thanks

G

Answer (score 2):

A package-level variable that is initialized via `init()` should work for your use case.